# Laravel view share doesnt work in modularing systems

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to do a view::share('current_user', Auth::User()); but in laravel 5 i can't find where to do this, in L4 you could do this in the baseController, but that one doesn't exists anymore.

Comment: You can use `View::share(...)` in the `boot()` method of a service provider. In your case it is some kind of redundant, as you can access the user by using `auth()->user()` in your views.

Answer (score 0):

You have to share the view in `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php`

```
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
```

And you have to use like this

```
public function boot()
{
    $user = Auth::User();
    View::share('current_user', $user);
    //dd($current_user);
}
```